# Return a field from a record when a specific column (the other field) is a certain value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

I have the following table with some data for illustration purposes:

```
user_id, creation_date, activity_date, net_revenue, retained_days

1, 2019/01/01, 2019/01/01, 0, 0
2, 2019/01/01, 2019/01/01, 0, 0

1, 2019/01/01, 2019/01/02, 0, 1
2, 2019/01/01, 2019/01/02, 0, 1

1, 2019/01/01, 2019/01/03, 0, 2
2, 2019/01/01, 2019/01/03, 0, 2
 
1, 2019/01/01, 2019/01/04, 5.5, 3
2, 2019/01/01, 2019/01/04, 0, 3

1, 2019/01/01, 2019/01/05, 5.5, 4
2, 2019/01/01, 2019/01/05, 3, 4
```

and I need to return the number of retained days when the revenue exceeded 0 for the first time for each user.

In this sample data, the desired output would be

```
1, 3
2, 4
```

I was trying stuff along the following lines:

```
SELECT DISTINCT uid, 
CASE
WHEN SUM(net_revenue) >0
THEN SUM(retained_days)
END AS ret_day_fst_purch
FROM table1 
GROUP BY 1
```

and (although I dont need the activity_date to be returned

```
SELECT DISTINCT uid, 
activity_date,
CASE
WHEN SUM(net_revenue) >0
THEN SUM(retained_days)
END AS ret_day_fst_purch
FROM table1 
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Yet it did not work, and I do see why, I just have a hard time to pivot to what I need.
Thank you in advance for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be simpler than what you initially thought, as you don't really need to sum and just filter the one case you want per user:

```
select user_id, min(retained_days) days_to_first_rev
from table1 
where net_revenue > 0
group by 1
```

So you basically are getting the minimum value of retained days in which you have revenue.

Comment: indeed, that worked just fine :D i had to put it in the WITH statement as there are other values I am retrieving. But a very simple solution sufficed ;D

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select *, 
  date_diff(
    parse_date('%Y/%m/%d', 
    activity_date), parse_date('%Y/%m/%d', creation_date), 
    day
  ) as retained_days
from your_table
qualify 1 = row_number() over revenue_days
window revenue_days as (partition by user_id order by sign(net_revenue) desc, creation_date)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]